# GetDataRange "Failed" or "Timed out"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Good Afternoon,

I have a web app and I have decided to make some changes to script and this hasn't worked our as planned.

Objective:  1) Get data from a sheet & 2) From a range on the sheet.

EG: Get data from the Sheet "Project" from range B1:E500, I have tried " and ' as not sure what it should be but regardless this errors and any help would be appreciated thanks.

Below is my code, but every time I run it I get an error in error in Google Dashboard.

> "Failed" or "Timed out"

```
function doGet(e) {

if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shProj = ss.getSheetByName("Projects").getDataRange('B1:E500').getValues();
  var shHier = ss.getSheetByName("Hierarchy").getDataRange('B1:F2000').getValues();
  var shFlr = ss.getSheetByName("Floors").getDataRange('B1:C300').getValues();
  var shRm = ss.getSheetByName("Rooms").getDataRange('B1:C500').getValues();
  var shCnd = ss.getSheetByName("Condition").getDataRange('B1:C50').getValues();
  var shSts = ss.getSheetByName("Status").getDataRange('B1:C50').getValues();
  var shRfg = ss.getSheetByName("Refrigerant").getDataRange('B1:C300').getValues();
  var shAcs = ss.getSheetByName("AccessE").getDataRange('B1:C50').getValues();
  
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"Projects":shProj,"Hierarchy":shHier,"Floors":shFlr,"Rooms":shRm,"Condition":shCnd,"Status":shSts,"Refrigerant":shRfg,"AccessE":shAcs,})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: "Failed" or "Timed Out

Comment: getDataRange() doesn’t accept parameters try getRange() instead

Answer (score 2):

As per Cooper's guidance I needed to use getRange() and this worked.